# Undefined class typecast

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile, casting

Good day.

Have a question with typecast. I have a undefined class that is created using NSClassFromString.
This class has a delegate parameter, which I have to assign, respectively, I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Class objectClass = NSClassFromString([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@Processor",processor]);
id processorObject = [[objectClass alloc] init];
(objectClass *)processorObject.delegate = delegate;
```

But it is clear that this does not pass ("Expected expretion").

How can I make such operation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`[processorObject setDelegate:delegate];`

You should ensure that corresponding headers for that class "XxxProcessor" exist and will be imported in this module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the problem is that these classes, I can not include in this module, as they can be a huge amount. And this is the condition that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: You need to include the headers, or alternatively a header of a base class or a `@protocol` that exposes the behavior you need in this module. That shouldn't be impossible ;)